# C++: Initialize template variable in struct

Tags: c++, templates, struct, constructor

UPDATE: The issue was stemming from the fact that the Passenger class does not have a default constructor. I don't understand why that breaks the list implementation though. If someone could leave a comment explaining this to me, I'd appreciate it a lot!

OG Post:

Hello fellow stackoverflowers. I'm working on a simple university assignment but have run into a problem I can't seem to wrap my head around to solve. I'm new to C++ and I'm learning now that implementing generics is not as straightforward in C++ as it is in Java. Inside my LinkedList class there is a struct Node:

```
struct Node {
    T data;
    Node *next;
}; // Node
```

Simple enough. And when I create a list of integers in my main.cpp, the implementation functions as it should.

```
int main() {
    LinkedList<int> integers;
    integers.append(1);
    integers.append(2);
    integers.append(3);
    // append, prepend, get, insert, and remove 
    // functions all work as they should.
} // main
```

I also have a Passenger class. The problem occurs when I attempt to create a list of Passenger instances.

```
int main() {
    LinkedList<Passenger> passengers;
    Passenger passenger1("LastName1", "FirstName1", 0);
    Passenger passenger2("LastName2", "FirstName2", 1);
    passengers.append(passenger1);
    passengers.append(passenger2);
} // main
```

The error messages read exactly as follows:

```
./LinkedList.hpp:21:10: error: implicit default constructor 
for 'LinkedList<Passenger>::Node' must explicitly initialize 
the member 'data' which does not have a default constructor

./LinkedList.cpp:26:23: note: in implicit default constructor 
for 'LinkedList<Passenger>::Node' first required here:
    Node *newNode = new Node;
```

The append function in the LinkedList class is the following:

```
template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::append(T data) {
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        newNode->next = head;
        this->head = newNode;
    } else {
        Node *ptr = head;
        while (ptr->next != NULL) {
           ptr = ptr->next;
        } // while
        ptr->next = newNode;
    } // if
    length++;
} // append
```

Thank you so much to anyone who helps me out here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you call:

```
    Node *newNode = new Node;
```

Which is equivalent to

```
    Passenger *newNode = new Passenger;
```

Which appears to be invalid because `Passenger` does not have a no argument constructor. I suspect you could fix this by doing:

```
    Node *newNode = new Node(data, nullptr);
```

Comment: Adding constructors to the Node struct does not fix the issue, but it got me to thinking about the fact that my Passenger class does not have a default constructor and has only one constructor which requires three parameters. That got me to thinking if adding a default constructor Passenger() would fix the issue. Sure enough, it did! I don't quite understand logically why not having a default constructor in Passenger breaks the list implementation. I'll look over and mull on it. I'll go ahead and mark your answer as the accepted one since it at least indirectly helped me solve my issue!

Comment: @OldLavyGenes474 Because calling `new Node` is trying to default construct a `Node` object; in order to do that all its members must be default constructible. Since `Passenger` doesn't have a default constructor, neither does `Node`, since `Node` contains a `Passenger`.